# Derivative of improper integral

Tags: calculus, integration

Please help me to show next equality:
$$\frac{d}{dr} \int\limits_r^\infty \frac{sg(s)\;ds}{\left(s^2-r^2\right)^{1/2}} = 
 r \int\limits_r^\infty \frac{g'(s)\;ds}{\left(s^2-r^2\right)^{1/2}}$$
g(s) is considered to be smooth enough. I tried to calculate left statement using the definition of derivative. Left integral's increment is
$$
\begin{align}
& \int\limits_{r+\Delta r}^\infty \frac{sg(s)\;ds}{\left( s^2 - (r+\Delta r)^2 \right)^{1/2} } - \int\limits_r^\infty \frac{sg(s)\;ds}{\left(s^2 - r^2\right)^{1/2}} \\  \\
& = \int\limits_r^\infty \left[ \frac{(s+\Delta r)g(s+\Delta r) }{\left( (s+\Delta r)^2 - (r+\Delta r)^2 \right)^{1/2}} - \frac{sg(s)}{\left( s^2 - r^2 \right)^{1/2}} \right] \; ds
\end{align}
$$
Calculation implies
$$\frac{d}{dr} \int\limits_{r}^{\infty} \frac{sg(s)\;ds}{\left(s^2-r^2\right)^{1/2}} = \int\limits_r^\infty \frac{s(r-s)g(s)+sg'(s)+g(s)}{\left(s^2-r^2\right)^{1/2}}\;ds$$
So I think it's a wrong way. After, i've tried to do the change s = ru. I've reached
$$
\frac{d}{dr} \int\limits_r^\infty \frac{sg(s)\;ds}{\left(s^2-r^2\right)^{1/2}} = 
 \int\limits_r^\infty \frac{s^2 g'(s) + sg(s) }{r \left(s^2-r^2\right)^{1/2} } ds
$$

Comment: Are there some hypothesis about $g$? Be careful during the calculation, the low bound is not constant. Maybe you should do the change $ru=s$ to make this bound constant.

Comment: It looks like there is some missing information about $g$ that will imply that these quantities are even defined in the first place.  Once you have that information about $g$, this looks like an application of integration by parts.

Comment: g(x) is smooth enough and it's all what I know about it.

Comment: Smooth doesn't seem to be enough, for example if we take $g=1$, the LHS doesn't exist. Did you try to show the result for example with $g(s)=\frac 1{s^2}$?

Comment: Yes, for $g(s) = \frac{1}{s^2}$ it works and equals $-\frac{\pi}{2r^2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
s & = r\sec\theta \\
ds & = r\sec\theta\tan\theta\;d\theta
\end{align}
$$

$$
\begin{align}
\int_r^\infty \frac{sg(s)\;ds}{\sqrt{s^2-r^2}}
& = r^2 \int_0^{\pi/2} (\sec^2\theta)\; g(r\sec\theta)\;d\theta.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thank you, it reduces my equality to a new one, that looks better

Comment: Problem is solved!

Comment: @Nimza: If you found Michael's answer useful, don't forget to click the check mark to the left of his answer.